# What's the temperature dependence of electrical conductivity for semi-metals?

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene

I am trying to teach undergraduate solid state physics when I realized that this problem is rarely discussed.

I know that metals' conductivity decrease with temperature due to increasing scattering at higher T.
And semiconductor has the opposite trend due to more excitation of electrons which increase the carrier density.

But semi-metal seems a bit weird, as it has zero DOS at Fermi level.
I would imagine that when T approaches absolute zero, the "valence band" become fully filled, and the "conduction band" becomes empty. So its conductivity should drop just like semiconductors.
However, I found somewhat contradicting results.

Graphene seems to fit my prediction, as shown in Figure 2 of https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1102896 .

But other materials look more like metals, shown in Figure 1 of https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/pssb.2220890226.

Is there a general trend for semi-metals? Or is it more complicated and material dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any material there are at least 3 mechanisms of scattering: impurities, phonon, e-e. Also graphene is different because of its 2D nature: this fact defines its DoS in form different from 3D metal. As i see in your second attached paper, the group interpreted their conductivity mechanism as electron-phonon one and confirmed it with some kinetics calculated based on collision integral. They treated this sample as a wire (they made it like that), so it was purely conductivity of this material. In the first attached paper the more complicated device is made: field-effect transistor: graphene on SiO2 in Si with source, drain and gate. Its conductivity is determined by the charge channel in the transistor which is created in the graphene after applying some gate voltage and it depends not on pure graphene's properties but more on gate-graphene contact band diagram properties. Mechanism of conductivity was at this time probably unknown (it is one of the first paper dedicated to experiments with graphene). So I don't think you can compare these two results so easily: it is just two different devices with probably two different main scattering mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right that I probably shouldn't compare those two results. Just out of curiosity, in 3D bulk semi-metal, do you know if there is a general trend for the dependence of conductivity on temperature?

Comment: I think it depends on the material you use. From kinetics for conductivity: $$ \sigma = -\frac{e^2}{D} \sum\limits_{ps} v_p^2 \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \epsilon} \tau_p $$ $\tau_p$ (relaxation time versus momentum) depends (for phonons in graphene it is $\propto p^{-1}$, for defects $\propto p$). To proceed with integration one should know E-k dependence near Fermi level. It differs for different semimetals (for mono graphene linear, for AB bilayer quadratic). So I think conductivity increase with T increase (more charge carriers because of band smearing), but the concrete law I can't give.